# Copying bone transforms from Blender to Unity, charcater get twisted up

Tags: python, armature

I am attempting to store rest-pose transform data from a rig in Blender to a .Json file so I may reference it later (in Unity) to set my character exactly as the Blender rest pose.

But when I apply the json to my Unity character, only the world postions work correctly, while if I set the rotations then my character becomes twisted up.

The below script I wrote in Blender to generate the .json result for each bone in the armature.

```
import bpy, json, math

armature = bpy.data.objects['Armature.001']

metaTpose = []

for bone in armature.pose.bones:

    e = armature.data.bones[bone.name].matrix.to_euler()

    rot = e#bone.matrix.to_euler()
    loc = bone.matrix.to_translation()

    rtd = 180/math.pi

    metaTpose.append( {"bone": bone.name, "position": {'x':loc.x,'y':loc.y,'z':loc.z}, "rotation": {'x':rot.x*rtd,'y':rot.y*rtd,'z':rot.z*rtd}} )

print("START OF DATA")
print(json.dumps( {"metadata":metaTpose} ))

#Example:
#START OF DATA
#{"metadata": [{"bone": "CC_Base_BoneRoot", "rotation": {"z": 0.0, "y": -0.0, "x": 0.0}, "position": {"z": 0.0, "y": 0.0, "x": 0.0}}, {"bone": "CC_Base_Hip", "rotation": {"z": 0.0004707553847656733, "y": 0.007201206346398633, "x": 90.00000250447816}, "position": {"z": 1.1287070512771606, "y": 0.024592161178588867, "x": 2.5310534965683473e-06}}, {"bone": "CC_Base_Pelvis", "rotation": {"z": -0.0003318526292683416, "y": 6.767367057499983e-05, "x": 11.542036150081067}, "position": {"z": 1.128706932067871, "y": 0.02459215186.....
```

[image]

Then in Unity I use those json results to apply the transform for each bone to my Unity character and attempt to position all bones exactly as the rest pose in Blender:

```
#LOCATION ONLY
foreach (var meta in metadata.metadata) {
    if (meta.bone.Equals (childBone.name)) {

        //childBone.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (meta.rotation.x, meta.rotation.y, -meta.rotation.z); #Notice this line is commented out!
        childBone.position = new Vector3 (-meta.position.x, meta.position.z, -meta.position.y);

        break;
    }
}
```

[image]

But notice that in the above I was only setting the position, and everything works as expected with the bones moving to the proper locations.

However I am having trouble when I attempt to also set the rotations:

```
#ROTATION AND LOCATION
foreach (var meta in metadata.metadata) {
    if (meta.bone.Equals (childBone.name)) {

        childBone.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (meta.rotation.x, meta.rotation.y, -meta.rotation.z);
        childBone.position = new Vector3 (-meta.position.x, meta.position.z, -meta.position.y);

        break;
    }
}
```

[image]

It seems that the local rotation that Blender is providing does not agree with Unity for some reason (or I'm calculating it incorrectly).

---

I have looked closely at the angles for some bones in both applications. I can see the angles of some bones are very close.

An example would be the "CC_Base_L_Upperarm" bone. Notice the rotation euler coming from Blender is almost the same as what is shown in Unity:

```
{"bone": "CC_Base_L_Upperarm", "rotation": {"z": -1.4407705622496563, "y": 0.07225991295297718, "x": 14.486447031456231},
```

[image]

But they are slightly different values, sign and different order.

How can I get the rotations/locations of all bones from a Blender rig so that I can use them directly on my Unity character?

I think I have gotten close, but I am struggling to make progress and am hoping someone can help me understand why it's not working or what I am doing wrong.